# when merge via hibernate, how can i find which property have changed?

Tags: hibernate, merge

i have done a modify operation via merge method:

```
ticketDiscountDAO.merge(ticketDiscount);
```

my problem is that how can i get  which property in  ticketDiscount have been  changed ?
just like that :
when property ticketname have been changed, i can find the property   ticketname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`merge()` function return new merged object

```
TicketDiscount merged = ticketDiscountDAO.merge(ticketDiscount);
```

you can check changed values between `merged` and `ticketDiscount` using reflection (or manually if the properties are a small number).
Another way could be use a [MergeEventListener](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/event/spi/MergeEventListener.html)

Comment: thank you very much! i just use the first method, and it works. but i don't understand the second method